# Debian wheezy: supervisor (install from repostiory) not start automatically on boot

Tags: debian, supervisord

I've been fighting with this problem for more than 1 hour and I have no idea what's going on.

Installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
Version: 3.0a8-1.1+deb7u1
$ sudo update-rc.d supervisor defaults
$ reboot

$ sudo service supervisor status
supervisord is  not running.
pid and socket are not created.
```

I manually try `sudo service supervisor start/stop/restart` and everything works...

here is the default [init script](https://gist.github.com/wppd/e5e39b7ff3b4439f85f8). Also, I simply run `sudo grep -ri 'supervisor'` in `/var/log` and can't find anything startup error.

Answer (score 3):

OMG, I just now realize that this may be because of the environment: Vagrant.

So, I remove my custom supervisor conf file which is calling a program in vagrant mounted filesystem.

reboot and boom! it works!

and the Vagrant solution is

`config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "service supervisor restart", run: "always"`